# Scroll hide problem in Lightbox2 (by Lokesh Dhakar)

Tags: lightbox, lightbox2

I don't want the scroll to be opened when clicking the image for Lightbox

Error link : https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HSzC8Ly.jpg

Source Code download link : https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

The height is taking a very high value. This height comes from the lightbox.js file. The overflow problem is troubleshooted when you do height:100% in the css class

Add the following line to the .lightboxOverlay class in css.`

```
.lightboxOverlay {height:100% !important; /* for Lightbox Scroll hide */}
```

Comment: If you implemented Lightbox correctly, that is exactly what happens when you put in the `disableScrolling` configuration option. The CSS that gets added when this option is true, is: `height: 100vh;` and `width: 100vw;` which means 100% of the viewport height and 100% of the viewport width. This class of yours does exactly the same. Ergo, you did not configure Lightbox correctly, or something else shady is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the option `disableScrolling` to prevent the page from scrolling while Lightbox is open:

```
lightbox.option({
  'disableScrolling': true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The alternative is to solve the problem